# Do something when app is open and received a notification

Tags: android, notifications, push

I'm asking a question to myself because, I saw on Windows Phone when the application is open and you just received a push notification, system is able to catch it and do some action such as refresh current view.

So my question is : Can we make it with Android ?

Comment: What kind of notification are you talking about?  Your question as it is is too vague.

Comment: Talking about pushed notification. From GCM for example